# How to read names and scores from csv file and sort them in ascending order and display them?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I want to sort the names and grades in ascending order in the loop below..
I want to write a program that reads the grades in ascending order with the name of each person from the csv file and prints it.
But I have trouble writing the program in the for loop. Please help me write the program according to the output so that it works according to the output.

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

def cc():
    with open('reders.csv' , newline='') as csvfile:
        sep = csv.reader(csvfile)
        av = list()
        for row in sep:
            q = list()
            name = row[0]
            for i in row[1:]:
                qq = []
                q.append(int(i))
                b = float(mean(q))
                c = str(b)
                qq.append(c)
```

output correct:

```
ali,5.0
hamid,6.066666666666666
mandana,7.5
soheila,7.833333333333333
sara,9.75
sina,11.285714285714286
sarvin,11.375
```

Please help me complete the code according to the output.

I want to take the names and grades of each person from the CSV file and calculate their grade point average and display the result in ascending order

Comment: GPAs and names were already given to a file csv
like this:
mandana, 5,7,3,15
hamid, 3,9,4,20,9,1,8,16,0,5,2,4,7,2,1
sina, 19,10,19,6,8,14,3
sara, 0,5,20,14
soheila, 13,2,5,1,3,10,12,4,13,17,7,7
ali, 1.9
sarvin, 0.16,16,13,19,2,17,8

Comment: Should the numbers be integer?  Is this correct `ali, 1.9`? If so, how did you get mean `5.0` from the data `1.9`?

Comment: Should the numbers be integer? Is this correct ali, 1.9? If so, how did you get mean 5.0 from the data 1.9? – Yuri Ginsburg 23 mins ago
In the form of float

Comment: So, why do you use `int` in your code?

Comment: I want to take the names and grades of each person from the CSV file and calculate their grade point average and display the result in ascending order

Comment: Names are string and grade are float. Why do you use `int`?
And I ask you again, How did you get the mean of 1.9 equal to 5.0?
Try the following in Python interpreter: `from statistics import meant; mean([1.9]). What result do you get?

Comment: Please provide the output that you get from *your* code.

Comment: output my code = ali,5.0
hamid,6.066666666666666
mandana,7.5
soheila,7.833333333333333
sara,9.75
sina,11.285714285714286
sarvin,11.375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

with open('d.csv' , newline='') as csvfile:
    a =  csv.reader(csvfile)
    for x  in a:
        print(x[0], mean([float(y) for y in x[1:]]))
```

d.csv:

```
mandana, 5,7,3,15
hamid, 3,9,4,20,9,1,8,16,0,5,2,4,7,2,1
sina, 19,10,19,6,8,14,3
sara, 0,5,20,14 
soheila, 13,2,5,1,3,10,12,4,13,17,7,7
ali, 1.9
sarvin, 0.16,16,13,19,2,17,8
```

output:

```
mandana 7.5
hamid 6.066666666666666
sina 11.285714285714286
sara 9.75
soheila 7.833333333333333
ali 1.9
sarvin 10.737142857142857
```